# rest assured check the name is exist in the json response

Tags: java, json, rest, hamcrest, rest-assured

Am new to rest assured.Using rest assured am trying to verify data  detail is found or not.Here two  data details present.Some times it will be 2 or 3 or 5
Am getting response as follows and using java

```
{
  "queryPath": "/api/",
  "nId": "f084f5ad24fcfaa9e9faea0",
  "statusCode": 707
  "statusMessage": "Success",
  "results": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10248522500798",
        "capabilities": [
          "record",
          "HDt"
        ],
        "name": "errt2"
      },
      {
        "id": "418143778",
        "capabilities": [
          "1record",
          "HDy"
        ],
        "name": "Livin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

code using

```
JsonPath jsonResponse = new JsonPath(response.asString());
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list = jsonResponse.get("results.data"); // 

if (list.size() < 1 ) {
    SpiceCheck.fail("data not found! " + list.size());
}
```

Rather than this i wwant to  check the data name is null or not also.How can i do that rest assured.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know you are missing a comma after 707.

To verify that none of the names is null I would parse out the names as a list, then iterate over the names one by one and check that they aren't null.

```
List<String> names = from(response.asString()).getList("results.data.name");
for(String name : names){
  if(name == null){
     // error handling code here
  }
}
```